# Convert 2d array column into flat array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "location_id" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "location_id" => 4
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "location_id" => 6
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "location_id" => 7
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "location_id" => 8
  ]
]
```

convert this into `["1","4","6","7","8",]`

So that I can use this array (`["1","4","6","7","8",]`) in different query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the laravel helper array flatten method:** Read more about it from here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-flatten

```
// Add the helper class call in the controller header
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

// The actual array
$array = [
    0 => [
        "location_id" => 1
    ],
    1 =>  [
        "location_id" => 4
    ],
    2 =>  [
        "location_id" => 6
    ],
    3 =>  [
        "location_id" => 7
    ],
    4 =>  [
        "location_id" => 8
    ]
];

// Flatten the array function
$result = Arr::flatten($array);
```

**Results:**

```
['1','4','6','7','8']
```

Comment: i have that type of answer but I need to use that array in laravel "WHEREIN" condition so need array like this ["1","4","6","7","8",].

Comment: @kinjalparmar that is exactly what flatten does, it gives you an array **['1','4','6','7','8']** if you are having a problem with using it in your query, its best if you post the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel Collection [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) method to only return property which you want from each array item, and after that flatten the result array with `flatten`

```
$data = [
    [
        "location_id" => 1
    ],
    [
        "location_id" => 4
    ],
    [
        "location_id" => 6
    ],
    [
        "location_id" => 7
    ],
    [
        "location_id" => 8
    ]
];

$result = collect($data)->pluck('location_id')->flatten();
```

Comment: Absolutely, I assumed his array was static as it is, forgot that it might include other data as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the laravel helper array pluck method Read more about it from here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-pluck

```
 $array = [
    0 => [
        "location_id" => 1
    ],
    1 =>  [
        "location_id" => 4
    ],
    2 =>  [
        "location_id" => 6
    ],
    3 =>  [
        "location_id" => 7
    ],
    4 =>  [
        "location_id" => 8
    ]
];
$data   = \Arr::pluck($array, 'location_id'); // [1,4,6,7,8]
$result = array_map('strrev', $data);
```

**Result**

```
["1","4","6","7","8"]
```